# Почему не выводиться на форму menuStrip1

Tags: c#

[image: items]   код формы

```
    namespace MVP_FruitStorage
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    
            private void asfasfsafToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                FruitStoragePresenter fruitStoragePresenter = new FruitStoragePresenter();
    
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: конструктор]
[image: Форма]

Comment: Покажите, что содержится в свойстве Items компонента MenuStrip

Comment: добавил картинку

Comment: FruitToolStripMenuItem поменял на это не работает

Comment: Покажите код Form1.Designer.cs полностью.

Comment: public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void menuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Слишком много добавил ресурсов(картинок) и он их не находил просто почистил все и заработало